# Using columns in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

So here I am trying to recreate a graph.

```
Subject Group   1   2   3   4   5   6 7 
1       A       45      45      45      45      80      80      80
```

So I grouped it by Group and col is Subject. However, I am not sure how to use multiple columns in the y-axis

`ggplot(stroke_data, aes(x = , y = , group_by("Group") ,col = "Subject" )) + geom_line()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am interpreting the question as saying you want the scores to define the y height, and want "25, 50, 75, 100" to be the tick marks (aka "breaks") on the y axis.

For tabular data like this, the idiomatic (simpler & more powerful) way to use `ggplot2` is to convert your data into long form, for instance using `tidyr::gather`. This makes the week a variable in a single column that you can assign to the x-axis aesthetic.

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr); library(ggplot2)
stroke_data %>%
  gather(week, score, week1:week7) %>%
  ggplot(aes(week, score, color = as.factor(Subject), group = Subject)) + 
    geom_line() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(25, 50, 75, 100)) +
  labs(color = "Subject")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Group the data and add the y axis to the filtered and grouped data:

```
    grouped_stroke_data = stroke_data%>% 
                               group_by("Group") %>% 
                                 mutate(yaxis= c(0,25, 50, 75, 100))
# A tibble: 5 x 11
# Groups:   "Group" [1]
  Subject Group week1 week2 week3 week4 week5 week6 week7 `"Group"` yaxis
    <int> <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <chr>     <dbl>
1       1 A        45    45    45    45    80    80    80 Group         0
2       2 A        20    25    25    25    30    35    30 Group        25
3       3 A        50    50    55    70    70    75    90 Group        50
4       4 A        25    25    35    40    60    60    70 Group        75
5       5 A       100   100   100   100   100   100   100 Group       100
```

You can add multiple plots(lines) to the plot keeping the same y axis and changing x each time:

```
ggplot(data=grouped_stroke_data, col = "Subject") + 
   geom_line(aes(x = week1 , y = yaxis,  col = "blue") ) + 
      geom_line(aes(x = week2 , y = yaxis,   , col="red") )
```